# can't set templates on CMS pages

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template

I'm trying to set a template for all CMS pages on my site
but I can't manage to do it, though the layout handle is detected :

```
<cms_page>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/cms_page.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addBodyClass"><class>test-class</class></action>
        <remove name="birdietown_homepage_mini_slider_our_brands"/>
        <remove name="birdietown_homepage_mini_slider_our_products"/>
        <remove name="birdietown_homepage_daclub"/>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

this layout XML node is detected, because the `test-class` is added to my page output, but the template is still `1column.phtml`. This handle is in `local.xml`

Comment: Please try

<cms_index_defaultindex>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/cms_page.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</cms_index_defaultindex>

Answer (score 2):

you cannot set the template via layout xmls for the cms pages.
I mean, you can, but it has no effect because what you set in the xml is overwritten later by the selection you make in the `Layout` dropdown for each page.
The `cms_page` handle is [loaded here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php#L97) but the root template set from the UI is [loaded lower in the code](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php#L100).
You can try to rewrite the method linked above and remove the applying of the root template.
But I don't think that's a good idea.
I would create a new page layout. [Here is how you can do that](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2013/03/add-custom-page-layout.html) Then assign all the CMS pages to that layout using the `Layout` field from the admin page edit screen.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i understand the issue a lot better now i think :) I managed to integrate the new template in the page layout list in backoffice, i'm now looking for a way to set my new page layout as default value for the option when creating a new page in admin

Comment: @Thomon. For that, you can rewrite the method `Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_PageController::editAction` and add a verification. If there is no page id passed in the request (you are on add page) then set your new layout to the page model. So for this [`if` statement](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php#L104) add an `else` branch that looks like this ` } else { if (!$id) {$model->setRootTemplate('your_page_layout_handle_here')}}`. (I didn't test the code but it seams like the way to go)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clue, i didn't manage to get the override to work at the moment but i can go forward in my project now that my CMs pages can have the right template :)

Answer (score 1):

In Magento pages are set based on `page_one_column, page_two_columns_left, page_two_columns_right and page_three_columns`

You can check it in page.xml file. You will need to create new cms page layout and can able to assign it from cms pages in admin

Check this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-cms-page-layout/) for how to add new cms page layout in Magento.